# Java enum usage in maps

Tags: java, enums, maps

So I am doing a project and got five different classes:

```
public class Article { ... } 

public class Shirt extends Article { ... } 

public class Boots extends Article { ... } 

...
```

Can I do something like

```
public enum Articletype {
    Shirt, Boots, ...
}
```

And use these enums in a map like

```
Map<Integer,Articletype> testMap = new HashMap<Integer,Articletype>();
```

How do I approach this?

I already got a map, which saves "Shirt"-Objects like

```
Map<Integer,Shirt> shirts = new HashMap<>()
```

I tried something like

```
Map<Integer,Articletype> testMap = new HashMap<Integer,Articletype>();
testMap.put(1,shirts.get(1001));
```

But this doesn't work. I don't think I completely understand these enum types but I know you can use these like this (or am i wrong?).

Anyway I kind of want to utilize them more often and I hope someone can bring some light this darkness.

Comment: What is the functionality you are trying to achieve? It would be better if you learn about *Enums* before trying to use them.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. When you create `Map<Integer,Articletype> testMap` it means that this map is supposed to hold `Articletype` *enum* instances (*values* defined in it: Shirt, Boots, ...), but those values have nothing to do with `class Article` `class Shirt` `class Boots` (except common name, but that doesn't create any obligation/contract). What are you trying to do anyway (lets try to avoid [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377))

Comment: Have you studied the [Oracle Tutorial on enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)? An enum is simply a way to conveniently and automatically instantiate upon class-loading some named *instances* (not types) as determined at compile-time.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answers. I should really read more about enums. My thoughts were complete non-sense. 
I wanted to create a map which stores all articles. A guy at my university said I should try to use enums (which I did and miserably failed). 
So can I just create a map like `map<Integer,Article> testMap`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use enums like that - which means you basically replace the current int representing type by the more expressive `enum` IIUC, but be aware it does have the disadvantage that it's less flexible when adding new article types. It really begs the question if its a good idea to use in this case.

What you can then do is maintain a `Map<ArticleType, List<Article>>` which would contain all the articles of the given type, eg

```
List<Article> allArticles = ...
Map<ArticleType, List<Article>> grouped = new HashMap<ArticleType,List<Article>>();
for (Article a : allArticles) {
    List<Article> ofType = grouped.computeIfAbsent(a.getArticleType(), ArrayList::new);
    ofType.add(a);
}
// and then you get all shirts by
List<Article> shirts = grouped.get(ArticleType.Shirt);
```

Note in Java 8 this can be done shorter using streams

```
Map<ArticleType,List<Article>> bytype = allArticles.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupBy(Article::getType));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no place for enums in the context of your `testMap`. What you want to store in the map are objects of types that extend `Article`. Using `Map<Integer, Articletype>` makes little sense, because you are not mapping article types to integers, but articles to integers.

---

There would be a valid case for using enums if you had to, for example, group all articles by types:

```
Map<ArticleType, List<? extends Article>> articlesByType = new HashMap<>();
List<Boot> bootList = ...
articlesByType.put(ArticleType.BOOT, bootList);
```